# Google Cloud Datastore performance (high latency)

Tags: java, performance, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have an API running on google app engine custom flexible environment. It's coded in java using spring-boot deployed with tomcat and uses the google cloud datastore client (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-datastore)

I am using newrelic to trace transactions and find bottlenecks and I came across something, as shown in the image:

[image: newrelic_trace]

I have 2 DAO classes that extend from a BaseDao with the datastore connection as shown in all examples:

```
private final Datastore datastore = DatastoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
```

why so many calls to **HttpURLConnection[datastore.googleapis.com]** (27.6 on avg, as shown in the image) ? Should I be fetching this connection differently somehow?

Just to be clear that's pretty much what the request does, which is nowhere near 27 calls to the datastore:

```
txn = datastore.newTransaction();
datastore.run(query1);
datastore.run(query2);
txn.put(entity1);
txn.put(entity2);
txn.commit();
txn.isActive();
```